# Symfony 3 persisting oracle datetime object ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Tags: php, oracle, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm working on a Symfony project and trying to insert a datetime object into an oracle Date column using doctrine. It seems the sql generated is using pure strings while I would expect the use of oracles [to_date](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) function.

am I missing something?

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO detail (id, code, descr, create_date, update_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [1527546, 60000, "description..", "2017-02-08 00:00:00", "2017-02-08 00:00:00"]:  ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

My Entity:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="detail")
*/
class Detail
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=9)
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="detail_id", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=6)
     */
    public $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    public $descr;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    public $create_date;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    public $update_date;
}
```

Controller:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $detail = new Detail();
    $detail->setCode(60000);
    $detail->setDescr('description..');

    $now_date = new \DateTime('now');

    $detail->setCreateDate($now_date);
    $detail->setUpdateDate($now_date);

    $em->persist($detail);
    $em->flush();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE Oracle session.

Comment: Why is this a solution? How/where is this change implemented?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Two ways:

- If you are able to do it, alter it to update the date column type from `DATE` to `TIMESTAMP` (Doctrine's mapped type for `datetime`).
- If you cannot update the old table (with created rows in it), create a custom `datetime_oracle` Doctrine type which forces the right format to include time ([gist link](https://gist.github.com/furtivesock/abbb6d07bf7188344be0e4db0951fa36)).

Hello!

I stumbled upon this issue. It took me one full afternoon to figure it out.
In my case, we couldn't simply modify the column type (which was `DATE`) in Oracle because it was an old table which was used by other apps. If you can do so, just update the type to `TIMESTAMP`. It's because Doctrine maps this type with native `datetime` type.

I couldn't find any answer addressing this issue exactly, so here's mine (for information, we're using Symfony 5 PHP framework):

### Non-working attempt

Firstly, I saw that it was possible to update the Oracle format, `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` used to store/read dates, which is defined at the beginning of the session, in the listener used in `services.yaml` config file:

```php
// Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\OracleSessionInit.php
protected $_defaultSessionVars = [
    'NLS_TIME_FORMAT' => 'HH24:MI:SS',
    'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' => 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT' => 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS',
    'NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT' => 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM',
    'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS' => '.,',
    'NLS_SORT' => 'BINARY_AI',
    'NLS_COMP' => 'LINGUISTIC'
];
```

When Doctrine persists a `datetime` value, it uses `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` which includes time, but it works only for Oracle's `TIMESTAMP` type. So if you can update the column with this type, do it.

`NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is used for persisting `date` values. As you can see, it does not include time.

If you bypass this default format to include time, like this:

```
# config/services.yaml
    my.listener:
        class: App\Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\OracleSessionInit
        arguments:
            - { NLS_DATE_FORMAT: "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS" }
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postConnect }
```

You will get a `ConversionException` when you will try to retrieve an entity with a `date` value :

```
Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ConversionException : Could not convert database value "2022-07-23 00:00:00" to Doctrine Type date. Expected format: Y-m-d
```

Because Doctrine's type `date` does not include time, it throws an error when formatting the value.

### Workaround

Create a custom Doctrine's type, I called mine `datetime_oracle`. One drawback if that if you change your database management system, you need to update the attributes using this type to `datetime`.

For the most part, I've reused what was defined in Doctrine's type `datetime` and I've defined `convertToPHPValueSQL` and `convertToDatabaseValueSQL` methods to force the right format (with time included) :

```php
    const DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

    public function convertToPHPValueSQL($sqlExpr, $platform)
    {
        return 'TO_CHAR('.$sqlExpr.', \'' . self::DATE_FORMAT . '\')';
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValueSQL($sqlExpr, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return 'TO_DATE('.$sqlExpr.', \'' . self::DATE_FORMAT . '\')';
    }
```

The gist can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/furtivesock/abbb6d07bf7188344be0e4db0951fa36).

That's all. Do not hesitate to update/improve my answer, I'm not an expert in Doctrine.